# How to neatly define an if conditional operation for a list of values in Helm template?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

There are, let's say, 10 environments (a-j) and I want a condition to be executed for (a-e) as done below in the Helm template:

```
{{- if or (eq .Values.env "env-a") (eq .Values.env "env-b") (eq .Values.env "env-c") (eq .Values.env "env-d") (eq .Values.env "env-e")}}
```

Now, instead of repeating the eq block so many times, is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no better way. You can check all available Helm Chart operators [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#operators-are-functions).